# Is it possible to have two different actions/buttons under one route in Flask?

Tags: python, post, button, flask

I am trying to create a simple web application where a user uploads two documents and has two choices of what to do with them: find the lexical differences or the semantic similarities. The 'Differences' button works fine, but I can not get the 'Similarity' button to work, or even be acknowledged it seems.

I tried messing around with if statements to see if any changes would matter, but I don't see any issues with my logic at the moment. However, I could definitely be wrong about that

routes.py

```
#snippet of code with relevant function
@app.route("/uploading", methods=["GET","POST"])
def uploading():
    if request.method =="POST":
        file1 = request.files['file1']
        file2 = request.files['file2']
        if request.form['differences']:
            result = dif(file1.filename,file2.filename)
            item = serve_pil_image(result)
            return item
        if request.form['similarity']:
            doc = (file1.filename).read()
            doc = gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(doc)
            doc2 = (file2.filename).read()
            doc2 = gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(doc2)
            new_vector1 = model.infer_vector(doc)
            new_vector2 = model.infer_vector(doc2)
            dot = np.dot(new_vector1, new_vector2)
            norma = np.linalg.norm(new_vector1)
            normb = np.linalg.norm(new_vector2)
            cos = dot / (norma * normb)
            return 'The similarity score between file one and file two is: ', str(cos)

 return render_template('upload.html')
```

---

upload.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple file upload using Python Flask</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="{{ url_for('uploading') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Choose the first file: <input type="file" name="file1" value="file one"/><BR>
            Choose the second file: <input type="file" name="file2" value="file two"/><BR>
            <input type="submit" name="differences" value="Find Differences">
            <input type="submit" name="similarity" value="Similarity Score (Percentage)">
        </form>
</html>
```

---

edit

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/sozube/PycharmProjects/pdf-diff/app/routes.py", line 108, in uploading
    if request.form['differences']:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 442, in __getitem__
    raise exceptions.BadRequestKeyError(key)
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'differences'
```

I am getting the error message werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError, with the KeyError: 'differences'

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't add a simple flag variable to the request header?

Comment: Please include the stack trace of the werkzeug exception; what line in your own code does it mention? (And please **edit your question,** don't just throw the trace in a comment.)

Comment: because i am new to flask (and web applications in general) and have not heard of a flag variable. i will look into that then.

Comment: as only one of the two keys - `differences` and `similarities` will be present you need to handle the missing key one way or another, e.g. use if/else instead of two ifs, use dict.get() or enclose the respective part in try/except block, etc.

Comment: @buran 
I tried using 'else:' instead of 'if request.form['similarity']:' but the error stays the same. Unless you meant something else?

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle that one of the two keys will not be present.

```
if request.form.get('differences'):
    # the body of if block here
if request.form.get('similarity'):
    # the body of if block here
```

alternatively

```
if request.form.get('differences'):
    # the body of if block here
else:
    # the body of else block here
```